# People API - Topic Search issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-people

When I use `Topic` search in `People API` - it does not get me a correct response.

When I search for `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search="topic:design"` - we got the following response:

```
{ "@odata.context": "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/…", "value": [] }
```

There are a lot of topics with respect to 'design' in our outlook but it doesn't show up.

Can someone guide us as to how this can be done?

Thanks,
Billy